# DateTimePicker needs multiple clicks of checkbox to fire OnValueChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, custom-datetimepicker

I am modifying some code that has a custom calendar control using a `DateTimePicker` for a `DataGridView`. I have set `ShowCheckBox = true` and I am trying to force it to change the value of the date to null when the user clicks on the checkbox (by changing the `CustomFormat` of the Date), which works. My issue is that it takes too many clicks on the checkbox to change the DateFormat. My basic CalendarColumn comes from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx, but that didn't include a checkbox and didn't allow null values.

My `OnValueChanged()` code is:

```
    protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell 
        // have changed.
        base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);

        if (this.Checked)
        {
            this.Checked = true;
            this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        } else if (!this.Checked)
        {
            this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            this.CustomFormat = " ";
        }
    }
```

The first click on the checkbox (when it's value is checked) greys out the date, but does not fire the `OnValueChanged()` method, the second click sets it back to "checked", and fires the event, and the 3rd click sets the `CustomFormat` to " " and therefore displays a null date as it should.

I've done some research, and I think that my issue is something to do with gaining focus of the cell on the first click, but if I put my check in the `onGotFocus()`, a single click will show/hide the date format as it should, but then when I click onto another cell after unchecking the checkbox, it remains with the `CustomFormat` set as " " rather than `DateTimePickerFormat.Short`.

Other answers on a similar subject refer to http://www.mofeel.net/70-microsoft-public-dotnet-framework-windowsforms/8806.aspx, but I'm confused as to how I would incorporate this into my code. I haven't posted the whole class, but can do if anybody thinks that will help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A collegue fixed this for me. I will try to explain as best I can:

My `OnValueChanged()` method ended up looking like:

```
protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
{
    valueChanged = true;
    // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell 
    // have changed.

    this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
    base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);

    isChecked();
}

public bool isChecked()
{
    bool isChecked = false;
     if (this.Checked)
    {
        this.Checked = true;
        this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        isChecked = true;
    }
    else if (!this.Checked)
    {
        this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        this.CustomFormat = " ";
        isChecked = false;
    }
     return isChecked;
}
```

He also added these methods:

```
protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
{
    isChecked();
    base.OnClick(e);
}     

public object EditingControlFormattedValue
{
    get
    {
        if (!this.Checked)
        {
            return String.Empty;                    
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.Format == DateTimePickerFormat.Custom)
            {
                return this.Value.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return this.Value.ToShortDateString();
            }
        }
    }
    set
    {
        string newValue = value as string;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue))
        {
            this.Value = DateTime.Parse(newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

The `InitializaEditingControl` was also edited to:

```
 public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object
        initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
 {
     // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value. 
     base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,
         dataGridViewCellStyle);
     ctl = DataGridView.EditingControl as CalendarEditingControl;
     // ctl.Invalidated += new InvalidateEventHandler(ctl_Invalidated);
     ctl.ValueChangedSpecial += new EventHandler(ctl_ValueChangedSpecial);
     if (rowIndex >= 0)
     {
         try
         {                    
             if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Value.ToString()))
             {
                 ctl.Checked = false;
                 ctl.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                 ctl.CustomFormat = " ";
             }
             else
             {
                 ctl.Checked = true;
                 ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.Value;
                 ctl.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;            
             }
         }
         catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException aex)
         {
             //MessageBox.Show("ERROR. " + aex.Message);
             ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.DefaultNewRowValue;
         }
     }
 }
```

And then it worked.

This answer is almost certainly unsatisfactory, but unanswered questions help nobody, so hopefully something here might help someone else.